# xsl: count() inside a value-of

Tags: xml, xslt

i have a problem about xsl syntax:
This is my xsl:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"   xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:html="http://www.w3.org/Profiles/XHTML-transitional"     exclude-result-prefixes="html">
 <xsl:output method="xml" omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="no"        encoding="utf-8" doctype-system="http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd"     doctype-public="-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" />
  <xsl:param name="objectDoc" />
 <xsl:template match="/">


                <xsl:for-each select="/articolo/foto-group/fg-foto">
                <div class="Image_container">
                      <div class="EM_Story_Image_{position()}"></div>
                </div>
                <div class="Caption"><xsl:value-of select="/articolo/foto-group[position()]/foto-dida"/></div>
                </xsl:for-each>

    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

And this my xml:

```
<articolo>
    <foto-group id="U50253517593AED">
        <fg-foto id="kYjG"/>
        <foto-dida class="dida" id="kSo">
            <p>Heloooooooooooo </p>
        </foto-dida>
    </foto-group>
    <foto-group id="U50253517593c0E">
        <fg-foto id="kNTF"/>
    </foto-group>
    <foto-group id="U50253517593h4B">
        <fg-foto id="kRtH"/>
    </foto-group>
</articolo>
```

What i have is this xml:

```
<!DOCTYPE div PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<div class="Image_container">
    <div class="EM_Story_Image_1"/></div>
<div class="Caption">Heloooooooo</div>
<div class="Image_container">
    <div class="EM_Story_Image_2"/></div>
<div class="Caption">Heloooooooo </div>
<div class="Image_container">
    <div class="EM_Story_Image_3"/></div>
<div class="Caption">Heloooooooo </div>
```

But what i expect is this:

```
<!DOCTYPE div PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<div class="Image_container">
    <div class="EM_Story_Image_1"/></div>
<div class="Caption">Heloooooooo</div>
<div class="Image_container">
    <div class="EM_Story_Image_2"/></div>
<div class="Caption"> </div>
<div class="Image_container">
    <div class="EM_Story_Image_3"/></div>
<div class="Caption"> </div>
```

So basically the instruction that is not working properly is this one:

```
<xsl:value-of select="/articolo/foto-group[position()]/foto-dida"/>
```

Cause instead of postion i would expect a number (1,2,3) as it works with

```
<div class="EM_Story_Image_{position()}"></div>
```

instead i obtain always the node one "Helooooooo" result from it as if there was no index.
I can see that i miss the {} around postion() but if i add them i obtain this xsl error:
Invalid XPath expression
Unexpected token - "{position()}]/foto-dida"
select="/doc/articolo/foto-group[{position()}]/foto-dida"

Does anyone know what i miss or what i should change? Thanks a lot

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's no reason to start at root in your select. The context is already `fg-foto`, so just get the `foto-dida` child of its parent. You should change your `xsl:value-of` to:

```
<xsl:value-of select="../foto-dida/p"/>
```

Answer (score 2):

At the point where that `<xsl:value-of>` is evaluated the current context node is an `fg-foto` element, so

```
<xsl:value-of select="../foto-dida" />
```

should give you the string value of the sibling `foto-dida` element.

Answer (score 1):

instead of

```
 <xsl:value-of select="/articolo/foto-group[position()]/foto-dida"/>
```

try this

```
<xsl:value-of select="current()/foto-dida"/>
```

Comment: This won't work because `current()` is `fg-foto` and not `foto-group`. (I made the same mistake initially because the indentation of the XML input example was misleading. I've since changed the formatting.)